# Let's Encrypt certificate renewal failure: "too many failed authorizations recently"

Tags: https, security-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am running a website on my Raspberry Pi with 2 different domain names.
Installing the certificate for `https://` when it became necessary was no problem. But renewing it seems impossible.

I have tried to renew it in many ways. The output says it is a recognized site but the program does not have enough access rights. Upon trying other ways I have now run out of opportunities having exceeded the rate limit.

This is the command I issued:

> sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html -d tgdn.nl -d www.tgdn.nl -w /var/www/html/erfgoed -d enkes-voorburg.nl -d www.enkes-voordburg.nl

And the error:

> An unexpected error occurred:
>
> There were too many requests of a given type :: Error creating new order :: too                    many failed authorizations recently: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/
>
> Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.

I cannot find anything that I see as a possible solution. 
Your input is appreciated.
Thanks,
Ton den Neijsel

Comment: As the message says, did you look at `/var/log/letsencrypt`?